# foreach loop showing only last record in codeigniter and get active records which was logged in 5 mins back

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi all i am trying to get active session users in codeigniter.So i am storing all my sessions in database and table name called ci_sessions and i got user data from ci_sessions table and i am trying to get user_name from data through foreach but i am getting only last active user.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ci_sessions');

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $session_data = $row->data;

    $return_data = array();  // array where you put your "BLOB" resolved data

    $offset = 0;
    while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) 
    {
        if (!strstr(substr($session_data, $offset), "|")) 
        {
            throw new Exception("invalid data, remaining: " . substr($session_data, $offset));
        }
        $pos = strpos($session_data, "|", $offset);
        $num = $pos - $offset;
        $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
        $offset += $num + 1;
        $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
        $return_data[$varname] = $data;  
        $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
    }    
}
echo $return_data['user_name'];

?>
```

Can anyone help me where i did mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You call echo only once..

Comment: do like this : $return_data[][$varname] = $data;

Comment: i am getting id of current user predeep '7' from another browser i logged in with different username.i could't bale to see that username

Comment: @Philipp what it mean philipp

Comment: @suresh the `echo`-statement, which prints the user name, isn't inside the foreach loop, so it always prints only the last record and `$return_data` is overwritten in each loop iteration

Comment: echo with print_r($return_data);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small mistake you have done

```
<?php
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ci_sessions');
$return_data = array();  // array where you put your "BLOB" resolved data
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
   $session_data = $row->data;

   $offset = 0;
   while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) 
    {
       if (!strstr(substr($session_data, $offset), "|")) 
        {
          throw new Exception("invalid data, remaining: " . substr($session_data, $offset));
        }
          $pos = strpos($session_data, "|", $offset);
          $num = $pos - $offset;
          $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
          $offset += $num + 1;
          $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
          $return_data[$varname][] = $data;  
          $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
      }

      }
     var_dump( $return_data['user_name'][0] );

     foreach($return_data['user_name'] as $onesession) {
          echo $onesession;
          echo '<br>';
     }

?>
```

$return_data = array(); I moved it out of foreach loop

Comment: still i can able to see only one record..but i logged in through two different browsers with different usernames

Comment: echo $varname; inside while loop and check the output, maybe it is same everytime..

Comment: result: __ci_last_regenerateis_loggeduser_namefirst_namelast_nameuserlevelorganisation_iduser_idpage_nameorg_idtemp_user_id__ci_last_regenerateis_loggeduser_namefirst_namelast_nameus

Comment: I have updated the code... $return_data[$varname][] = $data; put it like this and check

Comment: showing error from this line echo $return_data['user_name']; Array to string conversion

Comment: try print_r($return_data['user_name']);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172511/discussion-between-abuhuraira-lakdawala-and-suresh).

Comment: Array ( [0] => admin [1] => admin [2] => admin [3] => admin [4] => admin [5] => admin [6] => admin [7] => admin [8] => admin [9] => admin [10] => admin [11] => admin [12] => admin [13] => admin [14] => admin [15] => bharathi [16] => admin [17] => admin [18] => bharathi [19] => admin [20] => bharathi [21] => admin [22] => bharathi [23] => bharathi [24] => admin [25] => admin [26] => admin [27] => admin [28] => admin [29] => admin [30] => bharathi [31] => admin [32] => admin [33] => admin [34] => admin [35] => admin [36] => orguser [37] => admin [38] =>

Comment: yes now u can access this like $return_data['user_name'][0], $return_data['user_name'][1], or using a for loop...

Comment: $return_data['user_name'] = array_unique($return_data['user_name']);

Comment: if i want to show the users who logged in 5 mins before only?

Comment: there must be a timestamp in ci_session table ?

Comment: @suresh Your question and problem was about "but i am getting only last active user", if you have an other problem please edit your question :)

Comment: then in your first line change something like this $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ci_sessions where timestamp > '.time() - (5 * 60));

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-300' at line 1

Comment: $time = time() - (5 * 60); and check value.

Comment: when i am trying to get first_name i am getting error like illegal string offset